# Mongoengine's .limit() is not working properly

Tags: python, mongodb, pagination, mongoengine

I'm trying to implement pagination to my web app which is linked to a *MongoDB* database. I'm using *mongoengine* as an ORM, I've tested *.skip()* and it works fine. But *.limit()* is showing strange behavior. Given a list of objects, using .limit(i) on the list with different i values will return a wrong result.

Example:
Given a list of QuerySet objects named *objects*:

```
  LOG.info([object.uuid for object in objects])
  for i in range(len(objects)):
      LOG.info([object.uuid for object in objects.limit(i)])
```

Running the above code will show this output:

```
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,412: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('d821d3ae-25b2-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('0cecf672-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('3b07b682-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('61752d2c-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('92aab448-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('86972a50-25b4-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]

[2020-11-16 10:19:10,413: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] []
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,465: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,519: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,574: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,629: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('d821d3ae-25b2-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,738: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('d821d3ae-25b2-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('0cecf672-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,844: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('d821d3ae-25b2-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('0cecf672-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('3b07b682-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:10,951: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('d821d3ae-25b2-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('0cecf672-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('3b07b682-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('61752d2c-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
[2020-11-16 10:19:11,058: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] [UUID('92aab448-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('0cecf672-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('5463ad7e-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('d821d3ae-25b2-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('3b07b682-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('f2faff74-2595-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('9ae62614-25a0-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd'), UUID('61752d2c-25b3-11eb-9219-26ca0195c8bd')]
```

How can I fix this?